# Is there any way to create different vibrations for different messages in wear os in code?

Tags: wear-os, vibration

I want to send different vibrations to the watch depending on what message I am sending. I am open to use notifications or messages, but I want to control the vibration.

This is for a program so the subject knows if there is a positive response (say 1 quick vibration) or a negative response (a long vibration or two quick vibrations).

Can this be done? I essentially would want two buttons in an app sending different notifications with different vibrations to the watch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Just tag your message or notification with an ID indicating the type of vibration you want to trigger. On the watch make sure to check the ID and create the appropriate vibration pattern.

It might look something like this in your wearable code:

```
// Get the ID from the message/notification

// Create the vibration pattern
long[] pattern;
if(id == POSITIVE) {
    pattern = new long[]{0, 200, 50, 200};
} else if(id == NEGATIVE) {
    pattern = new long[]{0, 50};
}

// Trigger the vibration
((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

Remember to declare the vibrate permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```